# List of GNU packages for homebrew

Tags: command-line, homebrew

My team is working with Mountain Lion MacBook Pros, and we're using the GNU CLI tools, like `wget` and `watch`, intensively.

Whenever a new team member joins us, we tell the new hire to install homebrew and get the whichever CLI tool required by `brew install`.

We would like to automate the process, and prepare a list of GNU CLI tools which will be installed on every new machine.

Is there any list of classic GNU/Linux CLI tools available in homebrew?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

find, tar, awk, and sed are not included in coreutils:

```
brew install coreutils findutils gnu-tar gawk gnu-sed
```

You can use `brew search gnu` to search for other formulas where the name contains `gnu`.

Formulas for other commands that are not installed by default:

`brew install ack aspell dos2unix exiftool ffmpeg ghostscript iftop imagemagick lame multimarkdown netcat pandoc parallel pidof poppler pstree recode rename sox ssh-copy-id tmux tree watch wget xmlstarlet`

I tried running `compgen -c` on Ubuntu and OS X VMs and running this:

`comm -23 <(sort ubuntu) <(sort osx) | parallel -P10 brew info {} \> /dev/null 2\>\&1 \&\& echo {} | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '`

There were surprisingly few formulas, but the formula names don't always match command names:

`_lzma apg arping aspell dash dnsmasq dpkg duplicity enchant fribidi gcc gettext ghostscript gpg gs lesspipe logrotate lzma lzmainfo mawk mtools mtr netcat ntfs-3g pdftohtml pidof pkg-config pstree rename ssh-copy-id unlzma usbmuxd watch wget xz`